# how to query ArcGIS online rest service

Tags: arcgis

how do you query an arcGIS rest service to return values based on a sql statement...

I can query the object IDs successfully but I would like to use a where statement

[image]

when I include the where statement I get an error, ideally I would like to remove the object ID and just query the service.

any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes in your where clause. It should be something like `Owner = 'Parks'`